# unable to authenticate user properly

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I am creating an admin page that only allows user to access when they've logged in. When user tries to access the page directly, he will be re directed to login page with 'Please Login!'. That worked however, a weird problem came up.

The admin page has two features 'Edit Category' and 'Delete Category'.

When I tried to delete category on the delete page, I get kicked back to login page with 'Please Login!' even though I've already logged in. However, editing category works fine.

Below is the code for login,edit and delete page.

Login Page:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" name="login"/>
    </form>
</div>
            <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>


<?php 
include("includes/db.php");

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

    $query = "select * from admins where user_email='$email' AND user_pass='$pass' ";
    $popo = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($popo);
                if($check == 0)
                {
                    echo "<script> alert('Password or Email is wrong,try again!')</script>";

                }
                else 
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
                    echo"<script>window.open('index.php?login=Welcome to Admin Area!','_self')</script>";
                }
}
?>
```

Edit Category:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
{
    echo "<script>window.open('login.php?not_admin=Please Login!','_self') </script>" ;

}
else
{


if(isset($_GET['edit_cats']))

        {
            $cat_id=$_GET['edit_cats'];
        $query= "select * from categories where cat_id ='$cat_id'";
        $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
        $cat_id = $fetch['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $fetch['cat_title'];
                }
?>

<form action="" method="post" style="padding:80px;">
<b>Update Category:</b>

<input type="text" name="new_cat" value = "<?php echo $cat_title;?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="update_cat" value="Update Category"/>


</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['update_cat']))
{
$update_id=$cat_id;
$new_cat = $_POST['new_cat'];
$query=   "UPDATE  categories SET cat_title= '$new_cat' WHERE cat_id = '$update_id' ";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if ($run)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Updated!')</script>";

        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_cats','_self')</script>";
    } // display when product is added
        else{
            echo"Error in updating category"; // display when there is error
        }
}
?>
<?php }?>
```

Delete Category:

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
{
    echo "<script>window.open('login.php?not_admin=Please Login!','_self') </script>" ;

}
else
{


    if(isset($_GET['delete_cat']))

    {
        $del_id = $_GET['delete_cat'];
        $query= "delete from categories where cat_id='$del_id'";        
        $nob=mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if($nob)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('A category has been deleted!') </script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_cats','_self') </script>";

        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Unsuccessful in deleting category!";
        }
    }
}   
    ?>
```

P.S I've my session_start(); done on login & index page with edit and delete page included

Comment: The only difference I see between the working edit and the non-working delete is the include of `db.php`. What does it do?

Comment: so sorry for confusing you.. i've missed out the first line of edit page. Both has db.php and its for connection to mysql database.

Comment: PS: Your code is open to SQL injection, XSS and CSRF. To prevent them you should use prepared statements when passing data to the db, encode data when echoing it, and use an anti-CSRF nonce for actions that change state, respectively.

Comment: yes, i am aware of that. i prefer changing the code to prepared statement after i know the features have worked.. bad habit..

Comment: I think some relevant code is missing then. With the code you posted, there really doesn't seem to be a difference between delete and edit, so either both or neither should work. And it's really a bad habit to first write vulnerable code and make it secure later on, hoping to catch all vulnerabilities; it's way too easy to miss some. Posting vulnerable code on a public website is also not a great idea, as it normalizes insecure coding practices; less experienced people will see it and might emulate/copy it.

Comment: mm I'll try to find out where the missing code is.. and will take on your advice thanks.

Answer (score 0):

start your session

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Comment: oh i've done that for the login page and index page with edit and delete php included to index page using include function.. weird thing is it works for edit category but not quite for delete category..

Comment: yeah its weird , the first condition is true . . can you echo $_SESSION['user_email'] when deleting to see if it has value

Comment: yea the username came out as the login identity.. weird thing is when i press the delete button, it brings me back to the login page as though i've not log in